# Add watermark to image (Base64) and convert it

Tags: php, gd, watermark

I have this PHP script (below):
I getting base64 string using POST, than use imagecreatefromstring function and then trying to add watermark and save it. But the file is empty on the server after upload. What i'm doing wrong?

```
    <?php
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
    define('UPLOAD_DIR', 'img/');

    $base64 = base64_decode(preg_replace('#^data:image/[^;]+;base64,#', '', $_POST['string']));

    $stamp = imagecreatefrompng('img/wm.png');
    $im = imagecreatefromstring($base64);


    $marge_right = 10;
    $marge_bottom = 10;
    $sx = imagesx($stamp);
    $sy = imagesy($stamp);

    imagecopymerge($im, $stamp, imagesx($im) - $sx - $marge_right, imagesy($im) - $sy - $marge_bottom, 0, 0, imagesx($stamp), imagesy($stamp), 50);


    $file = UPLOAD_DIR . uniqid() . '.png';

    imagepng($im, $file, 100);


    echo 'ok';
    } else {
    echo "error";
    }


?>
```

Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

Comment: imagepng() accepts 3rd $quality argument which can be from 0 - 9 (all lossless, 9 is maximum compression). 100 is not an option. Not sure if this is error though.

Comment: Oh, sure!! Yes, you're right. changed the quality and it works fine!! thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this code before in order to check if your image was created

```
$im = imagecreatefromstring($base64);
if ($im !== false) {
    header('Content-Type: image/png');
    $marge_right = 10;
    $marge_bottom = 10;
    $sx = imagesx($stamp);
    $sy = imagesy($stamp);

    imagecopymerge($im, $stamp, imagesx($im) - $sx - $marge_right, imagesy($im) - $sy - $marge_bottom, 0, 0, imagesx($stamp), imagesy($stamp), 50);


    $file = UPLOAD_DIR . uniqid() . '.png';

    imagepng($im, $file, 100);
    imagedestroy($im);
}
else {
    echo 'An error occurred.';
}
```

//

Comment: image was created but also empty