# Adding watermark image to base64 encoded data in PHP

Tags: php, image-processing, base64, encode, watermark

I'm getting the uploaded image from mobile application to server through web-service as `base64` encoded form. Now I want to add an watermark image to that base64 encoded image.

So what is the best method to do this in `PHP`?

Comment: Here you find the solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35585358/add-watermark-to-image-base64-and-convert-it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add watermark to image (Base64) and convert it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35585358/add-watermark-to-image-base64-and-convert-it)